# What's the purpose of Edit > Copy in Rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox

I was trying to find a way to copy a song to folder while listen to it but Edit > Copy doesn't looks to work (it doesn't Paste neither a file nor a text information)

I'm using rhythmbox 2.97, ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you select a song under Music and then do Edit > Copy, you can then click on 'Play Queue' or a playlist (right click in the left bar and click 'New Playlist...' if you haven't made one before) and use Edit > Paste to place this song into the list.

You can also hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click multiple songs and then copy them en mass to a new playlist.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it should copy the song or the song info to the clipboard and I was supposing it was a bug.